# Appending data into an array when condition is met?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to keep a timer for users in my IRC.  When a user types a message I'm trying to insert the username & time of the message.  This is to stop spammers.

```
if(userList.Contains(username)) {
//check the time of message
//if last message is 3 seconds ago or greater, continue
} else {
//Add username & time into the array keeping all other values too
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to append data into the array.  I don't know how to copy the other existing array data into the new array with the new values. Can this be done?

Since array.Contains() doesn't work for two-dimensional arrays, what can I do to record the username and time? Should I insert data in two arrays?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Arrays generally have a static size. Why are you using it instead of one of the other implementations of IEnumerable (such as List)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C# are fixed size structures.

You want either a "List" which will allow you to implement this as a First In First Out queue, or, a "Dictionary" if you want to delete and insert at random.

Both these structures will allocate storage dynamically and allow you to expand and contract the number of users.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Although I feel "Lee Sy En"'s answer complete with code sample is better!

Answer (score 2):

You should have to create `List<T>` or `Dictionary<K,V>` instead of two-dim array. Firstly define a class (say `Message`) having UserName, TimeOfMessage and Message etc fields/properties and create `List<Message>.`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Code sample, this is rough idea, you can modify from here:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    var list = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
    list.Add("John", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
    list.Add("Mark", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-5));
    list.Add("Andy", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-5));

    PrintList(ref list);

    IsSpam(ref list, "John");
    PrintList(ref list);
    IsSpam(ref list, "Andy");
    PrintList(ref list);
    IsSpam(ref list, "Andy");
    PrintList(ref list);
}

private static void IsSpam(ref Dictionary<string, DateTime> list, string username)
{
    if (list.ContainsKey(username))
    {
        if (list[username] < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-3))
            Console.WriteLine("Not a spam");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Spam");

        list[username] = DateTime.Now;
    }
    else
    {
        list.Add(username, DateTime.Now);
    }
}

private static void PrintList(ref Dictionary<string, DateTime> list)
{
    foreach (var c in list)
        Console.WriteLine("user: {0}, time: {1}", c.Key, c.Value);
}
```